# Is there a standard datatype in C++ able to represent unset, set but empty, and set with a valid value?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm dealing with data items which basically can have three states:

1. not present
2. present and empty
3. present and not empty (valid value)

I'm currently implementing it with a `std::optional` to distinguish not present and present, and I use a special value to represent empty.

I've been thinking about using e.g. `std::optional<std::optional<int>>`, but before going down that route: is there some generally agreed upon data type available which is able to better convey the conceptual information?

Update:

To add a bit more context as to *why* I want to do this: I'm dealing with external messages which have certain optional data fields, and each of these data fields has a specific reserved value meaning *empty*, plus a restricted set of allowed values. Further down the processing chain, I need to be able to distinguish the three different states for each item, as different actions are supposed to happen in each case.

Update 2:

The value can for example be a value which is able to represent *empty* (like e.g. `std::string`), or a number, which has no concept of being empty.

Comment: You should strongly reconsider this design. "present but empty" sounds like a bad state for anything to be in, and it *will* led to confusion as to what is going on and why. I've tried something like that in a parser, and it was a *very* bad idea. I had to write extensive comments on very short functions just to be able to understand what the return values meant.

Comment: There's no standard type for that. Rather than force fitting std::optional I would recommend writing your own class/template.

Comment: Depends what you can do with "present and empty", but maybe variant could work for you: `std::variant<None, Empty, YourDatatype>` where `None` and `Empty` could be empty structs used as tags.

Comment: I agree with @pptaszni, but was going to suggest an optional of `variant<Empty, DT>`

Comment: it depend on what is *present but empty*. for example, empty `string` is no different from non-empty `string` and no need to differentiate when store.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::optional<std::optional<int>>` should give you what you want but may be syntactically difficult to use.

You could e.g. use a `std::variant` with custom types.

```
namespace my {
  struct missing{};
  struct empty{};

  template <typename T>
  using data = std::variant<missing, empty, T>;
}
```

Or you could write a custom data class that behaves as you need it.